# Draw Image and ImageObserver in Java Applet

Tags: java, graphics, applet

I'm using an applet to make a game and I'd like to make my characters be able to draw themselves in their own class. Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
public void drawPlayer(Image img, Graphics g)
{

    g.drawRect(0,0,128,128); //this is a test to see if it would draw a 
                                             //rectangle, which it did
    g.drawImage(img,0,0,128,128,0+128*x,128,128+128*x,128,GameMain);


}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to specify the ImageObserver. GameMain.class is the applet, but when I say this I get an error that says "cannot find symbol."

How can I tell java where to draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just supply `null` for `ImageObserver`, this will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
g.drawImage(img,0,0,128,128,0+128*x,128,128+128*x,128,this);
```

Above is the correct solution, assuming the `drawPlayer()` method is in the applet class.